# Error installing Easytag / Error running apt-update

Tags: apt

```
sudo apt install easytag
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 easytag : Depends: libid3-3.8.3v5 but it is not installed
           Recommends: yelp but it is not installed
 libtag1v5 : Depends: libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but 1.11-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.



sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 easytag : Depends: libid3-3.8.3v5 but it is not installed
           Recommends: yelp but it is not installed
 libtag1v5 : Depends: libtag1v5-vanilla (= 1.9.1-2.4ubuntu1) but 1.11-1ubuntu2 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I tried every command with no luck. sudo apt clean, sudo apt install -f, sudo apt install easytag. How can I Solve it?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the complete output to `apt-cache policy <package_name>` for each of the three packages listed in the error message.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?   The lib mentioned is available for 17.10-18.10 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtag1v5-vanilla), but the version you're trying to install is for 16.04 (xenial).  Check your sources, it looks like you've got a mixture of releases there.